# How can I make the gun rotate and shoot like lost control and shooting all around?

Tags: unity, c#

The shooting part I will make later. Now I'm trying to make the rotations part.

The first thing I did is to rotate the gun barrel and this is working fine.
The next thing I want to do is to rotate the gun body 360 degrees randomly so when the gun will shoot it will shoot randomly all around like lost control.

This is a screenshot of the gun barrel :

[image: Gun barrel]

And the gun body :

[image: Gun body]

By rotating the gun body 360 degrees randomly I want to create a lost control effect so it will shoot all around hitting randomly.

The script is attached to the top parent Drone :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] wings;
    public Transform[] propellers;
    public Transform gunBarrel;
    public Transform gunBody;
    public float propellersSpinSpeed = 50;
    public float wingsSpinSpeed = 50;
    public float gunBarrelSpeed = 50;

    private float angle = 360.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < propellers.Length; i++)
        {
            propellers[i].Rotate(0, propellersSpinSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < wings.Length; i++)
        {
            wings[i].Rotate(0, wingsSpinSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        gunBarrel.Rotate(0, 30 * gunBarrelSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

        gunBody.Rotate(Vector3.zero, angle * Time.deltaTime / 1.0f);
    }
}
```

I tried to do :

```
gunBody.Rotate(Vector3.zero, angle * Time.deltaTime / 1.0f);
```

But it does nothing not rotating it 360 degrees and I didn't use yet the Random.
The gun barrel keep rotating but the lost control shooting all around is not working yet not sure how to do it.

Update :

This is the current code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] wings;
    public Transform[] propellers;
    public Transform gunBarrel;
    public Transform gunBody;
    public float propellersSpinSpeed = 50;
    public float wingsSpinSpeed = 50;
    public float gunBarrelSpeed = 50;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < propellers.Length; i++)
        {
            propellers[i].Rotate(0, propellersSpinSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < wings.Length; i++)
        {
            wings[i].Rotate(0, wingsSpinSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        gunBarrel.Rotate(0, 30 * gunBarrelSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

        gunBody.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(gunBody.localEulerAngles.x, 0f, 90f), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The gunBody is now facing down.

This is a screenshot of what I want the gunBody to do :
I changed the gunBody on X and Z rotations a bit and this is the behaviour I want it to do randomly rotating on X and Z but not to pass too much up/down and left/right degrees.

The Z to be in range more or less 150, 205 and the X range of 55,100
And make it moving smooth randomly on this ranges. I'm not sure to the float point if those are the ranges but more or less this is what I mean by randomly moving in circles 360 degrees shooting all around like lost control.

[image: Drone]

Same behaviour of a turret trying to shoot on target and rotate 360 degrees in any direction the same thing here but only looking forward not backward. This is the logic I mean moving in circles and shooting around to the front.

Comment: Does `Vector3.zero` mean it won't rotate? You say it does nothing. That sounds like it is doing what you told it to do. It might be worth pointing out that you are suing a different overload to rotate the barrel.

Comment: I mixed it the line should be like this : gunBody.Rotate(gunBarrelSpeed * Time.deltaTime,0, 0); or gunBody.Rotate(gunBarrelSpeed * Time.deltaTime,0, gunBarrelSpeed * Time.deltaTime); but it's making the gun body rotate and I mean to make it move in circles not rotate around but make circles like shooting forward but 360 degrees.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your current code, and an example of the rotation you're observing.